# What is the size of the set of all possible functions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, set-theory, computer-science

If I have a general function F(x) what is the size of the set containing all possible functions? Its obviously some infinity bigger than countable infinity but what size is it?

Comment: Do you mean just all possible functions, or all possible functions with a given domain and a given codomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "set" of all possible functions is not a set, but a [proper class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)). If you consider the set of possible functions from $A$ to $B$ then it depends on the cardinality of $A$ and $B$ via [cardinal exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_exponentiation).